# Best way for a documentbuilder to parse xml with dtd in java web start

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dtd, java-web-start

Don't want to use File I/O for webstart.  So I used `builder.parse(xmlurl, base)` and worked.  But I was trying to reduce the traffic by putting the dtd and xml inside the jar file.  This also worked on a local test and on a static web server.  However, I wanted to use dynamic web server which distribute files using http://www.myserver.com/?file=start.jar

Now the problem is when the jar file runs, it tried to retrieve `jar:http://www.myserver.com/?file=start.jar!/Resource/xxx.xml` and the javaw complained that the `!/` wasn't in spec (complained from documentbuilder).  I think it just confused with the ? and & in the url for dynamic file accessing.

What is the best way to let the documentbuilder to retrieve an internal (in same jar) xml (and the corresponding dtd described in the xml) for dynamic served jar? Note that if I use this.class.getResourceAsStream() for xml then I still can't find dtd file.

### Update

I got a temporary solution but yet another problem.  This jar is stored in datastore, so I need http://www.myserver.com/?file=start.jar to access it.  Once I use http://www.myserver.com/start.jar it then works.  I just need my servlet to parse the Path which is still easy.

Another question I posted is related to this issue:

[Use GAE servlet to serve dynamic JNLP and jar for JavaWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108326/use-gae-servlet-to-serve-dynamic-jnlp-and-jar-for-javaws)

Comment: In what way is this Jar (& XML) 'dynamic'?  Is it generated per request, or just updated occasionally?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I got a temporary solution but yet another problem. This jar is stored in datastore, so I need http://www.myserver.com/?file=start.jar to access it. Once I use http://www.myserver.com/start.jar it then works. I just need my servlet to parse the Path which is still easy.

Comment: All my web files are stored in GAE DataStore with their revision. So the jar is one of the files and is updated occasionally (maybe once every 4 months after thorough testing, but will have some revision in a few years).